# C++ Calling Static member function from external file

Tags: function, static, call, external, member

I have this class defined in Global.h

```
    class Global
    {
     public:
         static string InttoStr(int num);
    };
```

In Global.cpp, i have

```
    Global::InttoStr(int num)
    {
        //Code To convert integer into string.
    }
```

Now, from SubMove.cpp, when i call Global::InttoStr(num) I get following error:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol Global::InttoStr(int) referenced in function SubMove::toString(void)

Then I made the function non-static and called it like so:

```
      Global g;
      g.InttoStr(num);
```

But the error still persists.

I thought it had something to do with extern and searched it but i could not make any connection. Please help.

Comment: Could you paste more relevant code? It's hard to imagine what the problem might be from your description. For example, it doesn't look as though "Global::InttoStr(int num) { ..." should compile.

Comment: Your definition, in Global.cpp, is missing a return value. Is that how the code is written, or just a typo in the question?

Comment: How do you compile? `gcc SubMove.cpp`? You need to include both .cpp files.

Answer (score 2):

First off, try this:

```
string Global::InttoStr(int num)
{
    //Code To convert integer into string.
}
```

Also, are you calling InttoStr from another library ? If so, you'll need to export the class "Global".

Best practice is to use a lib header (in the example below replace LIB_ with the name of the library):

```
#ifndef SOME_LIB_HEADER
#define SOME_LIB_HEADER

#if defined (LIB_EXPORTS)
    #define LIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define LIB_API __declspec(dllimport)

#endif // SOME_LIB_HEADER
```

Define LIB_EXPORTS in your project contianing Global, include the lib header in Global.h, then define the class like this

```
class LIB_API Global
{
    // some code for the class definition
};
```

Each project should have its own LIB_EXPORTS and LIB_API definition like DLL1_EXPORTS, DLL1_API, DLL2_EXPORTS, DLL2_API etc.

Basically this makes a separate lib treat the previous dll with __declspec(dllimport) and resolve all externs.

Comment: I just chased this bug for a bit because I had an enum as a return type and kept thinking I had properly declared by method in the cpp file; It would have helped GREATLY if you had "highlighted" string in the return type : ).